# $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^4 + 1}{z^2(\overline{z} - a)(b - \overline{z})} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let there be numbers ,$$0 < |a| < 1 < |b|$$
calculate the integral :

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^4 + 1}{z^2(\overline{z} - a)(b - \overline{z})} dz$$

I will provide the solution for this problem and I need some explanation if anyone may help.

On the circle $|z|=1$, we note that $z\bar{z} = 1$, so $\bar{z} = \frac{1}{z}$.

Therefore, we have three points, $0$, $\frac{1}{a}$, and $\frac{1}{b}$. However, since $|a|<1$, we note that $z=\frac{1}{a}$ is not in the given domain,Therefore, we are left with two singular points, $z = \frac{1}{b}$ and $z = 0$.

So we calculate the residue for these points. They did not show the calculation, but they said that $\operatorname{Res}(f,0) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Res}(f,\frac{1}{b}) = \frac{1+b^4}{b^4(b-a)}$.

can someone please explain to me how to culculate such thing with $\bar{z}$ ?

solution:
$\int\limits_{|z|=1} \frac{z^4 +1}{(1-az)(bz-1)} \mathrm{d}z$

$\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(z^2f(z))$ = $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(z^2\cdot\frac{z^4+1}{(1-az)(bz-1)})$
=$$\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\frac{-4abz^7+5az^6+5bz^6-6z^5+az^2+bz^2-2z}{\left(1-az\right)^2\left(bz-1\right)^2}$$=$0$

$\lim\limits_{z\to \frac{1}{b}}((z-\frac{1}{b})\cdot\frac{z^4+1}{(1-az)(bz-1)})$ =
$\frac{b^4+1}{b^3(b-a)}$

Comment: What does “calculate such thing with $\bar{z}$” mean? There is no $\bar{z}$ after you substituted $\bar{z} = 1/z$.

Comment: and am I allowed to do that when that's only correct on the boundary?

Comment: Yes, since the integral you want to compute is equal to$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^4+1}{z^2\left(\frac1z-1\right)\left(b-\frac1z\right)}\,\mathrm dz.$$

Comment: You integrate over the circle $|z|= 1$, where $\bar{z} = 1/z$, as you correctly said. So that substitution does not change the integral.

Comment: can I provide full solution and you check it for me ?

Comment: solution provided (mine) if someone may check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your calculation: There is no need to compute the residue at $z=0$, and the integral is $2 \pi i$ times the residue of $f$ at $z=1/b$.

For $|z| = 1$ is
$$
\frac{z^4 + 1}{z^2(\overline{z} - a)(b - \overline{z})}
= \frac{z^4 + 1}{( \overline{z}z - az)(bz - \overline{z} z)}
= \frac{z^4 + 1}{(1 - az)(bz - 1)}
$$
and the only singularity of $f(z)=\frac{z^4 + 1}{(1 - az)(bz - 1)}$ in the unit disk is a simple pole at $z=1/b$.

Therefore the integral is equal to
$$
 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}(f,\frac{1}{b})
= 2 \pi i \lim_{z \to 1/b} (z-\frac 1b)\frac{z^4 + 1}{(1 - az)(bz - 1)} \\
= 2 \pi i \lim_{z \to 1/b} \frac{z^4+1}{b(1-az)} =  2 \pi i \frac{1+b^4}{b^4(b-a)}
$$

Comment: thank you so much . but can you tell me 1 last thing , why I shouldn't calculate the residue at z= 0 or how can I say it's 0 ? , because our new function is analytic at 0 ,and for z=0 in the original function it's singular point that can be fixed?

Comment: @mayyashaj: “for z=0 in the original function it's singular point” makes no sense because $\frac{z^4 + 1}{z^2(\overline{z} - a)(b - \overline{z})}$ is nowhere analytic. But $f(z) = \frac{z^4 + 1}{(1 - az)(bz - 1)}$ is analytic at $z=0$, therefore $\operatorname{Res}(f,0) = 0$.

Comment: then how do we say that residue at z= 0 is equal to 0?

Comment: @mayyashaj: I do not understand your question. If $f$ is holomorphic at a point $a$ then $\operatorname{Res}(f,a) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

On the unit circle, the inegrand is $$\frac{z^4+1}{(1-az)(bz-1)}=\frac{((z-\frac{1}{b})+\frac{1}{b})^4+1}{(b-a)(1-\frac{ab}{b-a}(z-\frac{1}{b}))(z-\frac{1}{b})}$$ Upon expansion as a Laurent series in $z-\frac{1}{b}$, the coefficient of $(z-\frac{1}{b})^{-1}$ is seen to be $$\frac{\frac{1}{b^4}+1}{b-a}=\frac{1+b^4}{b^4(b-a)}$$